# Using the same data for SQL, NoSQL and NewSQL databases?

Tags: sql, benchmarking, nosql

Hey guys I am developing this research project where I want to benchmark different database systems.

I have a really huge relational database in **SQL**, and I need to make tests using the exact same data on **NoSQL** and **NewSQL** databases.

I was wondering how possible would it be, and which tools should I use, also how long would it take, as I only have a couple weeks to do so.

Is there any way to "translate" a SQL to MongoDB/Cassandra to NuoDB/VoltDB or so?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: What I am looking to achieve is a way to migrate data between SQL to NoSQL and NewSQL systems.

Comment: This is really broad. Plus it's a tool-recommendation question. And it's opinion-soliciting. Unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow (for those several reasons).

Comment: Even with your edit: Still off-topic. There's no "correct" answer to migration (it's going to be different for each database, for your environment, etc.). And "NoSQL" and "NewSQL" are relatively vague/meaningless terms, as they don't equate to a particular database type or brand. Just a general label representing the broad spectrum of non-relational databases.

Comment: Hi, Yann.   As far as "translate" - you'd have to write your own export/import tools.  Probably a different one for each database.  And despite others objecting about the (considerable!) differences between SQL/RDBMS and noSQL databases, yours is a fair question. The only way to answer it, however, is to construct and run your own benchmarks with your own data.  I hope the links below were helpful.

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4. I noticed that NuoDB has a tool to import from SQL databases, which is very helpful. Now I am trying to find something that could import SQL -> NoSQL. From SQLServer to MongoDB. Unfortunately I still have no idea how complex it would be to do so.

Comment: Yann, try looking at ClustrixDB (I work there) -- we're a MySQL compatible NewSQL database and have a specialized tool just for importing MySQL dump files quickly: http://docs.clustrix.com/display/CLXDOC/clustrix_import -- good luck with your research project!

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Atlas has several data import programs. Please view https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/#data-import-programs for documentation on MongoDB data import programs.
There may also be other third party tools available for importing a SQL database into a Mongo NoSQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* benchmark similar datasets and similar operations on NoSQL vs. SQL databases.  For example:

- [MongoDb vs SQL Server Basic Speed Tests](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1498/mongodb-vs-sql-server-basic-speed-tests.aspx)
- [Insert performance comparison of NoSQL vs SQL servers](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/insert-performance-comparison-of-nosql-vs-sql-servers)

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to "translate" a SQL to MongoDB/Cassandra to NuoDB/VoltDB or so?

No. Not only is there no way to translate SQL to Mongo or Cassandra, they're all very, very different systems with very different strengths and weaknesses, with different data models and access patterns/expectations.

You're trying to do an apples to apples comparison when you've got a bucket apples, apricots, kiwis, and tomatoes. The fact that you haven't yet realized your fruit has little in common other than the fact that it's fruit is scary. Benchmarking is hard, and you have to understand a database system before you can benchmark it properly.

Comment: I do know they don't have much in common. It would be weird if a relational and a non-relational database matched each other's structure. My question was if there is any available method on making the process more automate, rather than doing it all by hand.